# Grub installation error while installing ubuntu

Tags: grub2

I am trying to install Ubuntu on my Lenovo Ideapad 320 with Intel pentium processor. I have completely wiped windows earlier and now I am not able to install Ubuntu. While installing `grub2` it shows the error:

[image: Error Image]

The above picture shows the error and I am unable to figure a way out. I have tried googling it but failed to do a thing. Any help is appreciated or If you want more information let me know!!

**Edit**

Log of boot-repair: [Boot-repair log ubuntu-20.04](https://github.com/manishsencha/manishsencha/blob/main/Boot-Info_20210430_0707.txt)

Comment: Efibootmgr cannot read your UEFI boot entries. Never seen that. Can you go into your UEFI settings (not UEFI one time boot key) and look at all your boot entries & see if you can delete them there. Then see if efibootmgr can see UEFI entries. `sudo efibootmgr -v` See also `man efibootmgr` Only if that fixes UEFI, then try using Boot-Repair's advance mode to reinstall grub.